# Expiation (Kaffara) for hearing music?

Tags: halal-haram, music

This question is for those who believe Music is forbiden (Haram).

If someone hear music, is there any Kaffara (Expiation or atonement) mentioned in Islam to erase the sin ?

The reason I am asking is we can control what we can see but like that we cannot control what we can hear. For example, when we travel we hear many things and music can be one of this. We cannot shut our ears like we can close our eyes.

Jazzak Allahu Khaira

Answer (score 0):

Sin applies to willingly listening to music for getting pleasure from it. It does not apply to hearing it per se.

If you hear music then if you are able then you should put an end to it as part of enjoining good and forbidding wrong (الأمر بالمعروف والنهي عن المنكر).

> ولتكن منكم أمة يدعون إلى الخير ويأمرون بالمعروف **وينهون عن المنكر** وأولئك هم المفلحون
>
> And let there be [arising] from you a nation inviting to [all that is] good, enjoining what is right and **forbidding what is wrong**, and those will be the successful.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 3:104](https://quran.com/3/104?translations=20)</sup>

> من رأى منكم منكرا فليغيره بيده فإن لم يستطع فبلسانه
>
> Whoever among you sees an evil action, let him change it with his hand; if he cannot, then with his tongue
>
> <sup>— [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/1/84)</sup>

If you are not able to do that then you should not go to such a place or should leave it when you realize that there is music. And if you are not able then you should detest the music in your heart and you will not get sin for what you have no control over.

> فإن لم يستطع فبقلبه وذلك أضعف الإيمان
>
> ... and if he cannot, then with his heart and that is the weakest
> of faith.
>
> <sup>— [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/1/84)</sup>

As for expiation there is no specific expiation for listening to music just like there is no expiation for the majority of other sins. Just repent, ask forgiveness and do good deeds that will erase the sin.